# django context processors - how to return everything from one function?

Tags: python, django

I have added many context processors to my django test project thinking that adding many, would be OK.

But I have been told that I have too many and that each context processors is a "call" and each individual context processor will slow down my test project. This is true, b/c my test is now really slow.

I have been advised that I can group many of the related context processors as one, thus eliminating many of the calls to just one.

But I am unsure how to do this.

**How do I return everything from one function in a single dictionary and then display the required value on the template?**

Here is my common.py file where I declare the subscription prices & the context processors:

```
SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_FREE = 0
SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_03MONTHS = 40
SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_06MONTHS = 60
SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_12MONTHS = 99

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    ....
    'globalx.core.context_processors.get_subscription_price_free_user',
    'globalx.core.context_processors.get_subscription_price_03Month_user',
    'globalx.core.context_processors.get_subscription_price_06Month_user',
    'globalx.core.context_processors.get_subscription_price_12Month_user',
    'globalx.core.context_processors.get_subscription_price_default',
    ....
}
```

Here is a section of my context_processors.py file:

```
....
def get_subscription_price_free_user(request):
    return {'subscription_price_free_user': settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_FREE}

def get_subscription_price_03Month_user(request):
    return {'subscription_price_03Month_user':
        settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_03MONTHS}

def get_subscription_price_06Month_user(request):
    return {'subscription_price_06Month_user':
        settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_06MONTHS}

def get_subscription_price_12Month_user(request):
    return {'subscription_price_12Month_user':
        settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_12MONTHS}

def get_subscription_price_default(request):
    return {'subscription_price_default': settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_DEFAULT}
....
```

Here is how I display the value in the template:

```
{{ subscription_price_free_user }}
{{ subscription_price_03Month_user }}
{{ subscription_price_06Month_user }}
{{ subscription_price_12Month_user }}
{{ subscription_price_default }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOH!

The answer is so simple and obvious, and I was thinking that it would be deceptively difficult.

Here is my common.py file where I declare the subscription prices & the context processors:

```
SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_FREE = 0
SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_03MONTHS = 40
SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_06MONTHS = 60
SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_12MONTHS = 99

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    ....
    'globalx.core.context_processors.get_subscription_prices',
    ....
```

}

Here is my context_processor.py file:

```
def get_subscription_prices(request):
    return {'subscription_price_free_user': settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_FREE,
            'subscription_price_03Month_user': settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_03MONTHS,
            'subscription_price_06Month_user': settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_06MONTHS,
            'subscription_price_12Month_user': settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_12MONTHS,
            'subscription_price_default': settings.SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_DEFAULT}
```

This is how I call the values in the templates:

```
{{ subscription_price_free_user }}
{{ subscription_price_03Month_user }}
{{ subscription_price_06Month_user }}
{{ subscription_price_12Month_user }}
{{ subscription_price_default }}
```

I hope that this helps some one else.